# adobe illustrator - linework and paintbucket on different layers

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, layers, line-art

I would like to have my brush strokes on one layer and coloring done by live paint bucket on another layer. When I select the strokes and make a live paint group to color with everything, strokes and colors inside strokes become one object. Is there any way to seperate my brush linework and colors on different layers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate the line art layer and color that.

Live Paint objects have to be on the current layer.

Comment: But once I expand the paint group the strokes are all split into different pieces so deleting the duplicated linework becomes a hassle. I thought selecting similar stroke color would just select the strokes but when I delete the fill goes too.

Comment: No prob. Select same appearance does what I want.

Comment: @user1894167 alternatively, you can clear the lines before you start filling colors

Answer (score 0):

if you use the 'Live Paint Bucket' Tool (k) to fill the areas required you can use the 'Live Paint Selection' Tool (Shift+L) to select an area and cut and paste it into another layer.

If you have multiple areas of colour, select one area with Shift+L > Select > Same > Fill Colour, to select all the same coloured areas